# Is it still an antipattern if we log an exception message and throw a different exception?

Tags: java, anti-patterns

Our webapplication is using an `ExceptionMapper` to map some exceptions to `Response`. We log the exception messages before throwing a new exception as follows:

```
catch (SomeException ex) {
  LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
  throw new MyException(ex.getMessage());
}
```

We are **not re-throwing the same exception**, so my question is if this would be considered a [Log and Throw antipattern](https://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns#logAndThrow). And thus, would it be better to remove the logging in similar places and move them to the several `ExceptionMapper` classes as follows:

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {

  // bla bla 

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(final MyException ex) {
    LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
    return Response.status(400).entity("something").build();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would stop you as soon as you logged `ex.getMessage()`, that's already wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you report the message text of exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320080/should-you-report-the-message-text-of-exceptions)

Comment: Arguable, [reporting the message text of exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320080/should-you-report-the-message-text-of-exceptions) is [always a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7320220/545127).

Comment: IMO it is not really fair to not mention at all that this is a webservice. That really does change the game rules, because for example just using regular exception handling mechanics can be a security risk; you do not want any and all exception to just be sent back in a 500 error response, that needs to be checked and filtered. Aggressive on-the-spot logging is also far more common when dealing with systems that have external clients directly invoking it. Logging stacktraces in service calls that get invoked repeatedly can lead to unmanageable log file sizes and performance problems.

Comment: @Gimby In this case OP doesn't send any error details in the response (probably a boilerplate "error occurred" content). Also, how do you diagnose a problem without a stacktrace? Rolling loggers routinely take care of storage size and log data is embarassingly compressible.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your code actually sports not one, but *three* antipatterns:

1. log and rethrow;
2. rethrow without wrapping the original cause;
3. log only the message and not the stacktrace (this is the worst one).

If you followed the best practice to:

1. not catch at all (let the exception propagate on its own);
2. if forced to catch a checked exception, wrap into unchecked and rethrow;
3. never log anything except at the top level;
4. log the entire exception stacktrace with `log.error("Error occurred", e);`

then you would not face any dilemmas, including your current one, because the logged stacktrace would include all the wrapped exceptions as well.